# Why is second fork needed here?

Tags: system-verilog

Why second fork is needed in below link
[Wait for only some threads to complete after fork join_none in SystemVerilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911060/wait-for-only-some-threads-to-complete-after-fork-join-none-in-systemverilog/75944259#75944259)

```
fork : first_fork
     process_that_will_never_end();
join_none

fork begin : second_fork
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) 
     fork : third_forks
       automatic int k = i;
       process_that_must_end(k);
     join_none
   wait fork;
end join
```

Can below work?

```
begin
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) 
     fork : third_forks
       automatic int k = i;
       process_that_must_end(k);
     join_none
   wait fork;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the second `fork/join`, the `wait fork` statement hangs waiting for the `process_that_will_never_end()`.

The `second_fork` creates an isolation thread so the `wait fork` inside that scope so in no longer waits for the first thread since it is no longer an immediate child process of the statement executing the `wait fork`.

Comment: If there was no first_fork, will wait_fork in the below code wait for `process_that_must_end` to finish?

`begin
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) 
     fork : fork_a
       automatic int k = i;
       process_that_must_end(k);
     join_none
   wait fork;
end`

Comment: It will wait for _all_ the forked `process_that_must_end` to finish.

Answer (score 0):

`wait fork;` is a special SytemVerilog statement. Described in [IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 9.6.1 *Wait fork statement*:

> The `wait fork` statement blocks process execution flow until all immediate child subprocesses (processes created by the current process, excluding their descendants) have completed their execution.
>
> The syntax for wait fork is as follows:
>
> ```
> wait fork ; // from A.6.5
> ```
>
> Specifying `wait fork` causes the calling process to block until all its immediate child subprocesses have completed.
>
> ...

Your code kicks off 40 threads in parallel that are in independent `fork`-`join_none`. They are in the same scope as the `wait fork`, therefore the process will be time blocked until all the `process_that_must_end(k)` threads complete.